# Gráficos en interfaz de usuario de KIVY

Tags: python, kivy, plotly

Necesito sacar un gráfico hecho con plotly que me genera una función, en un boxlayout de una screen en kivy y no lo consigo.

El error está en que el gráfico no se muestra. La ventana sale negra en vez de con el gráfico dentro. Este es el código que tengo:

Esta es la ventana donde quiero mostrar el gráfico

```
 class IgleScreen(Screen):

    ###PRIMER GRAFICO
    #Dejar solo la columna necesaria
    df1 = ds.drop(ds.columns[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]], axis='columns')

    #Ordenar valores del 0 al 5
    orden = df1.sort_values('Churches', ascending=True)

    #Calcular nota media de las reviews
    total = 0
    for value in orden.index:
        total = orden['Churches'][value] + total
    media = total/len(orden)
    media = "{:.2f}".format(media)
    #print("{:.2f}".format(media))

    #Cuantas veces sale cada nota
    cantidad1 = orden['Churches'].value_counts()

    #Ordenar de menor a mayor
    cantidad1 = cantidad1.sort_index()

    #Crear un nuevo dataframe con valores y las veces que sale cada valor
    graf1 = pd.DataFrame(cantidad1)
    graf1_reset = graf1.reset_index()
    graf1_reset.columns = ['Values', 'Quantities']

    #Asegurar que en el gráfico salen la misma cantidad de notas que de reseñas
    # cuantos = 0
    # contador = 0
    # while contador < len(graf1_reset['Quantities']):
    #   cuantos += graf1_reset['Quantities'][contador]
    #   contador += 1

    #Visualizar dataset final
    #print(graf1_reset)

    #Crear gráfico a partir de los datos
    fig = px.scatter(graf1_reset, x = 'Values', y = 'Quantities', trendline= 'lowess', trendline_options=dict(frac=0.1),  color = 'Values', color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn, 
        title = 'REVIEWS DE IGLESIAS' + '\t'*190 + 'PUNTUACIÓN MEDIA: ' + str(media))
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                              line=dict(width=2,
                                        color='DarkSlateGray')),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))

    #fig.show()
    def build(self):
        box = self.ids.box
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(fig.gcf()))
        return box
```

Y este es el trozo de .kv para la ventana:

```
<IgleScreen>:
    name: 'iglesias'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0,0,0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        size_hint_y: .8
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
```

Es un verdadero quebradero de cabeza

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Qué error te sale? Por favor [edit] la pregunta y añádelo

Comment: Ya la he actualizado, gracias.